# How to add a param to the route tabset components in ngx-admin nebular and angular 5

Tags: angular2-routing, angular5

i need to add a param to the route tabset component in ngx-admin nebular and angular 5 as follow:

```
tabs: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'My tab 1',
      route: '/pages/projects/edit/tab1/:id',
    }...
]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I am currently using.

#### TS

```
tabs: any[];

async ngOnInit() {
  const id = await getIdLogic();
  this.tabs = [
    {
      title: 'Tab 1',
      route: `.../.../${id}`
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

And then in you HTML you need to remember to only render the nb-route-tabset component once the tabs have been set.

#### HTML

```
 <nb-route-tabset *ngIf="tabs" [tabs]="tabs"></nb-route-tabset>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the best solution, but I just used this work around

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.key = this.router.url.split('/')[3];
}
```

I handle all the security inside the main component that calls

```
<nb-route-tabset [tabs]="tabs" fullWidth></nb-route-tabset>
```